# JFreechart href action not properly (missing serie and X item) generated with a XY line chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I've a XY Line chart properly generated but I'm facing the following issue:

There HREF action generated changes the value fetched from the query and displays their array position. Therefore, the tooltip generated is ok so I think the `XYdataset` used to generate the graph and the area map is ok. Here are the data

This is the SQL used to generate the dataset.

```
SELECT distinct v.station_name as STATION,date_part('month',(v.billing_time)) as MONTH_NUM,count(*) as TRANSACTIONS
FROM vista_all v
where v.station_ind=v.station_ind
and v.station_medmat='MED'
group by v.station_name,MONTH_NUM
ORDER BY station_name;
```

And here are an example of the first row returned by the query:

OBSERVACIO |2| 1.6768

OBSERVACIO |3| 716

UCI        |3| 2.990

UCI        |4| 3.529

I Use the following code to generate my graph:

```
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(graphicTO.getLabelX());
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(graphicTO.getLabelY());
XYItemRenderer xyRenderer = (XYItemRenderer)new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
xyRenderer.setDefaultToolTipGenerator((XYToolTipGenerator) new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
                                                
StandardXYURLGenerator url = new StandardXYURLGenerator(any_action, "series", "DrillDown"); 
xyRenderer.setURLGenerator(url);
                        
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, xyRenderer);
plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
                        
chart = new JFreeChart(title, JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
```

So, I expect that the tooltip generated in my graph will be "OBSERVACIO: 2, 1.6768" with the first line and "UCI: 3, 2990" and this is ok and works smoothly.

Problem is that the url generated in the series line are the following:

```
any_action&series=0&DrillDown=0
any_action&series=0&DrillDown=1
any_action&series=1&DrillDown=0
any_action&series=1&DrillDown=1
```

And I was expecting

```
any_action&series=OBSERVACIO&DrillDown=2
any_action&series=OBSERVACIO&DrillDown=3
any_action&series=UCI&DrillDown=3
any_action&series=UCI&DrillDown=4
```

Something like is using the array position instead of the values itself.

Any idea? The graph visually is OK, and the dots are in the proper position, I mean I think the dataset is ok.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Ivan

Thank you!

Comment: Is the series parameter name named "series"? That's confusing to me.

Comment: This is the expected behavior; the `prefix` parameter is typically a URL, and the other two parameters become request parameters to be interpreted by the request handler, e.g. `http://example.com/?series=0&item=1`.

Comment: @hfontanez yes it is :)

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the clarification. I though that this was not the expected behavior. As soon as I figured out I notice that I only need to override the generateURL method in order to return the data that I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @Ivan cut the "update" part and paste it as an answer. You can answer your own question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @trashgood I had to develop a tool that replicated a legacy one. I don't know why they changed the standard implementation but who knows. I only have to return the same href that the other one and that's it. I think that they use the "Drilldown" value to generate a SQL or something like that... Who knows!

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up generating a class implementing the `XYURLGenerator` interface with exactly the same code as `StandardXYURLGenerator`, with the only difference in the method `generateURL`, that now returns the data that I needed.

```
@Override
public String generateURL(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item) {
    String url = this.prefix;
    boolean firstParameter = !url.contains("?");
    url += firstParameter ? "?" : "&amp;";
    url += "series" + "=" + dataset.getSeriesKey(series)
        + "&amp;" + "DrillDown" + "=" + dataset.getXValue(series, item);
        return url;
}
```